# How do I hide a console window that is running a java program?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, hide

I have a program that creates a batch file which in turn runs the program on startup. I want to hide the batch file so that all the user sees is the java program open, not the console window in the background.

EDIT: It seems that I'm not being clear. Here is the code in the batch file:

```
cd C:\Java\jre8
javaw -jar C:/Users/Me/Desktop/MyProgram.jar
```

I only need to hide the batch file.

Comment: If you're on Windows, just use `javaw` and not `java`. If this isn't applicable, give more information on your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*javaw* seems to be what you are looking for: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

> The javaw command is identical to java, except that with javaw there
>   is no associated console window. Use javaw when you don't want a
>   command prompt window to appear. The javaw launcher will, however,
>   display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails for some
>   reason.

If you are looking to hide the windows .bat console, you can use vbs -- take a look at this page for various options for doing this: https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file .